# ForeignKey django 1.1.1 model

Tags: django, django-models

I have

```
class staff_name(models.Model):

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=150)



class inventory_transaction(models.Model):

    staffs = models.ForeignKey(staff_name)
```

I want to get or create staff surname and first name through inventory_transaction

I used these code below

```
inventory_transaction.objects.get_or_create(staffs__surname__contains=sname,staffs__firstname__contains=fname)
```

I got this error `"staffs__surname__contains can not be defined"`

What have i done wrong ?

thanks

Comment: @Spikie: Here's request; Please Use Upper Case Letters for Proper Nouns like "I".  You can update your question to make it readable, you might get better answers if you question looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm based on the documentation of `get_or_create()`:

> In English, that means start with any non-'defaults' keyword argument that **doesn't contain a double underscore (which would indicate a non-exact lookup)**.

I would say what you want to do is not possible as your query *could* return more than one result. The arguments passed to `get_or_create()` must be in a way that a unique result is returned.

You could try `__exact` instead of `__contains`:

```
inventory_transaction.objects.get_or_create(staffs__surname__exact=sname,staffs__firstname__exact=fname)
```

But I don't think that `get_or_create()` can create foreign key objects automatically.

So probably the easiest thing in this case is this:

```
try:
    itrans = inventory_transaction.objects.get(staffs__surname__contains=sname,staffs__firstname__contains=fname)
except inventory_transaction.DoesNotExist:
    staff = staff_name(firstname=fname, surname=sname)
    staff.save()
    itrans = inventory_transaction(staffs=staff)
    itrans.save()
```

Btw common practice is to use capital names for classes and I wouldn't use underscores as they are also used in DB lookups. That said, rename your classes to `StaffName` and `InventoryTransaction`